# How to initialized Set variable in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, constructor, set, required

I use dart 2.13.3 . In my flutter app I can't initialized `Set` variable without required annotation.I want to build constructor without `final Set<V>initialSelectedValues;`
or without `required`, because from another call this parameter is just optional. But show error and suggest me to add required annotation at the front of  `final Set<V>initialSelectedValues;`. How to I change and solve this error?

```
class MultiSelectDialog<V> extends StatefulWidget {
  MultiSelectDialog({required this.items,this.initialSelectedValues});

  final List<MultiSelectDialogItem<V>> items;
  final Set<V>initialSelectedValues;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MultiSelectDialogState<V>();
}
```

```
final selectedValues = await showDialog<Set<int>>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return MultiSelectDialog(
          items: items,
          //initialSelectedValues: [1,2].toSet(),
        );
      },
    );
```

Comment: Declare your constructor with a `Set` literal as the default argument:  `this.initialSelectedValues = <V>{}`

Comment: Now I can solve base on your answer. You are close enough, but need `const` in optional default argument. Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, I can solve this. Change to default parameter with `const` .

```
MultiSelectDialog({required this.items,this.initialSelectedValues = const {}});

  final List<MultiSelectDialogItem<V>> items;
  final Set<V> initialSelectedValues;
```

Answer (score -1):

Every final variable must have a value, if you want to set them through the constructor you have to put "required" in front of every parameter.

```
MultiSelectDialog({
  required this.items, 
  required this.initialSelectedValues });
```

Comment: I want to use `initialSelectedValues` for optional only, When I used `required` annotation make me force to add this parameter always when calling this constructor. If I don't add  that `required` annotation, show error to initialized this variable in constructor.